# Finding out the magnitude of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

The question is to find out the magnitude of $z$ if $z=(1+i\tan A)^{i+1} $

My book gives the following solution

$(1+i\tan A)^{i+1}=e^{(1+i)(\ln (1+i\tan A)}=e^{(1+i)(\ln(e^{iA}/\cos A)}=e^{-(A+\ln \cos A)+i(A-\ln \cos A)}$ Then this step puzzles me They wrote $|z|=e^{-(A+\ln \cos A)}$ I couldn't get why this is true.Any ideas?

Comment: What is $A$? A real number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$e^{-(A+\ln \cos A)+i(A-\ln \cos A)}=e^{-(A+\ln \cos A)}e^{i(A-\ln \cos A)}$$
and 
$$
|e^{i(A-\ln \cos A)}|=1
$$

(Remember the polar form $z=\rho e^{i\theta}=|z|e^{i \arg z}$)